# Phonegap build, iOs Android app: opening a link inside the app

Tags: php, android, html, ios, cordova

I have a php website that is live on webserver,

From my understanding I see that I cannot make a index.php page as the home page of my app. As an alternative I have made an index.html page and put a link in it that points to my php page.

I am using phonegap build to compile the app

The error that I am getting is that the link is opening in the default web browser of my phone instead of within the app itself.

In the html page title I have added

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

In the config.xml file I have added

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
 <access origin="http://mydomain" subdomains="true"/>
```

I have tried [www.appsgeyser.com](http://www.appsgeyser.com) and my website opens up within the app itself in the android apk that I made over there ( in fact while making the app i only provided my website landing php page and it worked perfectly , so there has to be a way to use php in phonegap) , but they don't have an option to build in ios and I would like to use phonegap build instead.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how responsive your index.php file is, an easy fix would be to place an iframe in your html.index file.

So something like this:

```
<body>        
<iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;border:none" 
src="http://***path-to-your-php-file***.php" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   app.initialize();
</script>
</body>
```